# Open local image in canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm trying to make an javascript image color picker.
It is possible to open local image in canvas, without uploading it to server ?

```
function draw() {
    var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function(){
        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
    }

    img.src = $('#uploadimage').val(); 
}

<input type='file' name='img' size='65' id='uploadimage' />
```

Comment: Erm, why not? Specify relative path.

Comment: You could with [offline applications](http://www.w3.org/TR/offline-webapps/).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Not supported in all browser (IE and Opera AFAIK) but you could get a data URI using the [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/)

```
function draw() {
  var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d')
    , img = new Image()
    , f = document.getElementById("uploadimage").files[0]
    , url = window.URL || window.webkitURL
    , src = url.createObjectURL(f);

  img.src = src;
  img.onload = function(){
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
    url.revokeObjectURL(src);
  }
}

<input type='file' name='img' size='65' id='uploadimage' />
```

I added a [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/fWLJ9/) as an example.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following for jQuery use:

```
$('#load-button').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  $('<input type="file" accept="*.png">').change(function(){

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event){

      var img = new Image();
      img.onload = function(){
        $('#canvas')[0].getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0, 0);
      };

      img.src = event.target.result
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
  }).click();
});
```

These are the elements:

```
<canvas id="canvas">
<button id="load-button" type="button">Load</button>
```