# Populate HTML CANVAS with local device file

Tags: javascript, android, html, canvas, intel-xdk

I'm building an HTML5 application for Android, using Intel XDK. And I try to load in a Canvas an image stored locally on the device, in the application Temporary file system.

I base myself on *[Open local image in canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10209227/open-local-image-in-canvas)* :

```
this.dirEntry.getFile(imagePath, {}, function (fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.file(function (file) {
        console.log("Loading " + file.fullPath +" to canvas");
        var ctx = container.getContext('2d');
        var img = new Image();
        var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        var src = url.createObjectURL(file);

        img.onload = function () {
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
            url.revokeObjectURL(src);
        }
        img.src = src;
    });
}, function (evt) {
    console.log(evt);
});
```

When I testing with IntelXDK and Weirn , I get:

```
Loading file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.intel.html5tools.apppreview/cache/repositories/00001/summary.jpg to canvas
processMessage failed: Error: TypeError: Type error
processMessage failed: Stack: TypeError: Type error
    at load (file:///data/data/com.intel.html5tools.apppreview/files/appmobicache/nE5zi-ycD6TAzOFeh0Y3aXzMHLix6sA22cSUzZ6e3lo/4.0.0/js/app.js:248:27)
    at file:///data/data/com.intel.html5tools.apppreview/files/appmobicache/nE5zi-ycD6TAzOFeh0Y3aXzMHLix6sA22cSUzZ6e3lo/4.0.0/js/app.js:271:21
    at win (file:///android_asset/www/plugins/org.apache.cordova.file/www/FileEntry.js:71:9)
    at Object.cordova.callbackFromNative (file:///data/data/com.intel.html5tools.apppreview/files/appmobicache/nE5zi-ycD6TAzOFeh0Y3aXzMHLix6sA22cSUzZ6e3lo/4.0.0/cordova.js:292:54)
    at processMessage (file:///data/data/com.intel.html5tools.apppreview/files/appmobicache/nE5zi-ycD6TAzOFeh0Y3aXzMHLix6sA22cSUzZ6e3lo/4.0.0/cordova.js:1039:21)
    at Function.androidExec.processMessages (file:///data/data/com.intel.html5tools.apppreview/files/appmobicache/nE5zi-ycD6TAzOFeh0Y3aXzMHLix6sA22cSUzZ6e3lo/4.0.0/cordova.js:1076:13)
    at pollOnce (file:///data/data/com.intel.html5tools.apppreview/files/appmobicache/nE5zi-ycD6TAzOFeh0Y3aXzMHLix6sA22cSUzZ6e3lo/4.0.0/cordova.js:944:17)
    at pollOnceFromOnlineEvent (file:///data/data/com.intel.html5tools.apppreview/files/appmobicache/nE5zi-ycD6TAzOFeh0Y3aXzMHLix6sA22cSUzZ6e3lo/4.0.0/cordova.js:939:5)
processMessage failed: Message: S01 File1974092051 {"lastModifiedDate":1413544852000,"fullPath":"file:\/\/\/storage\/emulated\/0\/Android\/data\/com.intel.html5tools.apppreview\/cache\/repositories\/00001\/summary.jpg","type":"image\/jpeg","name":"summary.jpg","size":91793}
```

When I test with the application directly (thus built and deployed on the device) (and using Weirn too), I get:

```
Loading [object Object] to canvas
processMessage failed: Error: TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found that matched the signature provided.
processMessage failed: Stack: TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found that matched the signature provided.
    at TypeError (native)
    at load (file:///android_asset/www/js/app.js:248:27)
    at file:///android_asset/www/js/app.js:271:21
    at win (file:///android_asset/www/plugins/org.apache.cordova.file/www/FileEntry.js:72:9)
    at Object.cordova.callbackFromNative (file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:292:54)
    at processMessage (file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:1039:21)
    at Function.androidExec.processMessages (file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:1076:13)
    at pollOnce (file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:944:17)
    at pollOnceFromOnlineEvent (file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:939:5)
processMessage failed: Message: S01 File1409319454 {"lastModifiedDate":1413530713000,"fullPath":"\/repositories\/00001\/summary.jpg","type":"image\/jpeg","name":"summary.jpg","size":91793}
```

An idea what's wrong ?

Comment: Found a solution by any chance?

Comment: Not for the moment. I let this piece of code aside. Due to lack of reaction here I opened a ticket on IntelXDK's forums. See this [thread](https://forums.html5dev-software.intel.com/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=7890). Not more answers. But probably better follow-up.