# Fill svg element with local image

Tags: javascript, html, file, svg, input

I want to fill a svg element e.g. a `circle` element with an image that the user can select from his local computer via a `<input type='file'/>` input.

I know that you can fill a svg element using a pattern:

```
<defs>
  <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100" height="100">
    <image xlink:href="wall.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" />
  </pattern>
</defs>
<circle cx=100 cy=100 r=100 fill="url(#img1)" />
```

But I can't get it to work with a local Image.

A working fiddle would be amazing :)

Related Issues:

[Fill SVG path element with a background-image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796025/fill-svg-path-element-with-a-background-image)

[Open local image in canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10209227/open-local-image-in-canvas)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work in latest Chrome and Firefox.

First, HTML part:

```
<input id="upload" type="file"/>

<svg>
    <defs>
        <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100" height="100">
            <image xlink:href="wall.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" />
        </pattern>
    </defs>
    <circle cx=100 cy=100 r=100 fill="url(#img1)" />
</svg>
```

Next, JS part:

```
var upload = document.getElementById('upload');
var patternImage = document.querySelector('#img1 image');
var currentBlobData = null;

upload.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
    var file = this.files[0];
    if (currentBlobData) {
        URL.revokeObjectURL(currentBlobData);
    }
    currentBlobData = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    patternImage.setAttribute('xlink:href', currentBlobData);
});
```

Finally, a working fiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/5qLb9m1t/

Answer (score -1):

You will find [a decent example here](http://srufaculty.sru.edu/david.dailey/svg/intro/PartF_C.html). It uses a minimum of JavaScript to update the `pattern`. Adapted to your given code, the result could look like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script> 
var E; 
function prepare(){ E=document.getElementById('imgPath'); } 
function change(v){ E.setAttribute("xlink:href", v); } 
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="prepare()">
    <table border="2">
      <tr><td><input type="file" formmethod="GET" onchange="change(this.value)" /></td></tr>
      <tr><td>
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" width="320" height="286" viewBox="0 0 320 86">
          <defs>
            <pattern id="imgPattern" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100" height="100">
              <image id="imgPath" xlink:href="wall2.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" />
            </pattern>
          </defs>
          <circle cx=100 cy=100 r=100 fill="url(#imgPattern)" />  
        </svg>
      </td></tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

It just gets the `id` for the image path with JavaScript and then sets the SVG's `xlink:href` attribute triggered by the `onchange` event.

Comment: with this I get an `Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/fakepath/***.jpg` Error..